# Cargar diferentes archivos con .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lo que quiero lograr es mediante `js` - `jquery` y/o `ajax` generar un `switch` parecido al de `PHP` mediante botones en `<nav`.

Es decir:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".click").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("/file.php");
     });
    });
```

---

```
<div id="box">

</div>
<a href="#" class="click">Cargar</a>
```

Esto cargaría file.php en elemento con id `#box` al hacer click en elemento con clase `.click`

**Lo que quiero lograr:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadFiles()" id="1"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadFiles()" id="2"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadFiles()" id="3"></a>
<div id="contenido-dinamico"></div>
```

Cuando `onclick="loadFiles"` se ejecute, cargue X archivo según el `id="file(numero)"` Pero con la **condición** de que cuando se cargue 1, el 2 y el 3 no se muestren.

**¿Es esto posible?**

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres que se cargue el archivo segun el id del elemento al cual se le da clic?

Comment: Si. Se va utilizar en un menu para cargar los files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías pasar los **"id"** como parametro de la función javascript loadFiles() que definiste en el código de la descripción de tu pregunta.

Para garantizar que el **div** dinámico sólo muestre la información que deseas es necesario usar **.empty()** para "limpiar" el contenido anterior del **div** y colocar la nueva información que mostrará el **div**.

Por último pasas el **"id"** por post o get al archivo que deseas cargar dentro del **div** (en tu caso **"file.php"**) para que cuando cargues el archivo selecciones según el **"id"** la información que mostrarás en tu **div dinámico**.

He aquí el código que contempla toda la explicación anterior:

```
<div id="box"></div> 

<a href="#" name="dinamico" id="1">menu 1</a> 
<a href="#" name="dinamico" id="2">menu 2</a> 
<a href="#" name="dinamico" id="3">menu 3</a> 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('a[name="dinamico"]').click(function(){ 
id=$(this).prop('id'); 
$("#box").empty(); 
$("#box").load("/file.php", {id:id}); 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

**Para file.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];

if($id=="1"){
// Aquí va información 1 para div dinámico
}
elseif($id=="2"){
// Aquí va información 2 para div dinámico que es distinta a 1
}
else{
// Aquí va información 3 para div dinámico distinta a 1 y 2
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery te podria proponer lo siguiente:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id")
        $("#box").load("/"+id+".php");
    });
});
```

El html :

```
<a href="#" class="click" id="1">Archivo 1</a>
<a href="#" class="click" id="2">Archivo 2</a>
<a href="#" class="click" id="3">Archivo 3</a>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Si quieres usar una funcion puedes hacerlo igual asi:

```
function loadfile(el){
     var id = $(el).data("id")
     $("#box").load("/"+id+".php");
 }
```

El html :

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadfile(this)" id="1">Archivo 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadfile(this)" id="2">Archivo 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadfile(this)" id="3">Archivo 3</a>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Si, esto es posible, puedes llamar la función `loadFile` con el parámetro `id`
de manera que quede algo así:

`<a href="#" onclick="loadFiles(1)" id="1"></a>`

De forma que cuando des click se cargue solo el archivo al id que quieres:

```
function loadFiles(id){
    $("#box").load("/file.php?id="+id);
}
```

Entonces en el archivo `file.php` debes mostrar la información que quieres según el valor de la variable `id`

Esta es una manera de hacerlo para mostrar el archivo `file.php` en el elemento `div` `box`